# Erro na hora de converter String em JSONObject

Tags: android, json

estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação em android que consuma um Web-Service mas sempre que tento executar uma consulta no Banco de Dados ele me retorna este erro:

> Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Na minha LogCat:

```
02-22 15:37:32.250: I/Choreographer(1446): Skipped 232 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 15:37:36.712: I/Choreographer(1446): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 15:37:37.959: I/Choreographer(1446): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 15:37:38.611: E/JSON Parser(1446): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-22 15:37:38.612: D/All Products:(1446): {}
02-22 15:37:38.612: W/System.err(1446): org.json.JSONException: No value for success
02-22 15:37:38.613: W/System.err(1446):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
02-22 15:37:38.613: W/System.err(1446):     at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:478)
02-22 15:37:38.614: W/System.err(1446):     at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:134)
02-22 15:37:38.614: W/System.err(1446):     at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
02-22 15:37:38.684: W/System.err(1446):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-22 15:37:38.685: W/System.err(1446):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-22 15:37:38.693: W/System.err(1446):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-22 15:37:38.693: W/System.err(1446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 15:37:38.693: W/System.err(1446):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 15:37:38.694: W/System.err(1446):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:37:39.680: I/Choreographer(1446): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 15:37:41.397: I/Choreographer(1446): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Ele diz que o erro esta no metodo doInBackground da linha 134, e o que tem nela é:

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Minha Classe que gerecia essa consulta:

AllProductsActivity.java

```
package br.com.products;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://XXX.XXX.X.X/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = new JSONArray();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Ja procurei e nao acho que o erro seja proveniente do meu script php, tanto que o erro aponta na hora da conversao, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

`org.json.JSONException: No value for success` Esta linha no *LogCat* indica que  o valor de `success`é nulo.

Quando ele é atribuído à variável `success` em `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` dá erro.
O erro ocorre porque o tipo *int* não permite nulos.
A forma de contornar o erro é declarar o tipo como String.

```
String success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Julgo, no entanto, que deve rever a origem do *json* e verificar se é válido `success` retornar nulo.

Comment: mas como aplico isso ao meu codigo @ramaral? viu o restante do codigo depois dessa int? se eu coloco isso da erro no restante do metodo

Comment: Por isso é que eu disse para rever a origem do json, pois julgo que não é suposto `success` ser nulo. No entanto pode ultrapassar isso fazendo, em vez de, `if (success == 1)`, fazer `if (success == "1")`

Comment: mesma coisa @ramaral, nao mudou nada, percebe-se que ele retorna org.json.JSONException: No value for success, significa que nenhum valor foi retornado, o que pode ser?

Comment: quando tento fazer a busca pelo meu navegador ele me retorna isso: {"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"iPhone","price":"4500.00","created_at":"2015-02-18 20:02:20","updated_at":""},{"pid":"2","name":"Motorola Moto G 2014","price":"800.00","created_at":"2015-02-19 18:56:46","updated_at":""},{"pid":"4","name":"LG G3","price":"1200.00","created_at":"2015-02-19 21:49:25","updated_at":""}],"success":1} / no final retorna success:1, é isso que esta alimentando a variavel né? será que minha aplicação nao esta conseguindo pegar ela?

Comment: Veja no *log* produzido por esta linha: `Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());` se está `"success":1`.

Comment: esta vazia essa linha

Comment: Isso quer dizer que não está retornando nada na linha `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);`. O *URL* pode estar errado!

Comment: ramaral, fiz essa consulta no meu navegador e retornou todos os dados, entao o url esta certo... será que o erro esta no script php?

Comment: O WebService está na sua máquina? Você está a correr o programa no emulador ou num celular/Tablet?

Comment: Esta no localhost, estou usando Wamp Server